# Convert MySql to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

I want to move from MySQL to PostgreSQL, this is not a live site as yet, going to launch soon and the schema is all ready in MySQL but given the business model I want a better scalable DB, so to convert MySQL to PostgreSQL, do i need to do it manually table by table or are there are GUI tools I can use (or scripts) to automate this conversion for tables/file values?

My app is written in codeingiter PHP.

Comment: I have no experience in migrating to PostgreSQL so I can't say for sure, but it sounds kind of like a bad idea to switch databases when launch is imminent.

Comment: true but better to do the switch now before i go live than later once i have live user data and may run into down times/issues.

Comment: I hope you have a very good test suite. MySQL tends to be a bit more forgiving/DWIPM (Do What I Probably Mean) than PostgreSQL.

Comment: It is all manual testing for now. Go page by page and see all data is recorded properly in backend and nothing blows up.

Comment: Test any queries with a GROUP BY -- PostgreSQL doesn't support [MySQL's hidden columns "feature"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html).  There are lots of other subtle differences -- changing DB vendors is a very large undertaking.

Answer (score 7):

The only thing did the job for me was [Navicat Premium](https://www.navicat.com/products/navicat-premium), You can grab Navicat and use it free for 14 days, which is enough for DB migration...

Just create 2 connections (one source mysql, another target postgresql), and choose Tools -> Data Transfer, and it works!

Other tools I tried: 
dumping with mysqldump as postgresql compatible - didn't work, as ansi sql - didn't work, tried pgload - didn't work, tried with 
https://github.com/AnatolyUss/nmig
Nmig created tables properly but data was missing.

Comment: you saved the day. Thanks! Everything is very simple and easy

Comment: thank you ! this is the only thing wich worked for me on windows

Comment: In 2023 this still works and was the easiest for me. Downloading and install Navicat Premium and using the 14 day trial was very simple ... no CC required, no registration required. Just download and install.

Answer (score 2):

1. I agree with Pekka: if you're going to launch soon, the last thing you want to do is switch database systems.
2. If you're lucky and you're able to export compliant SQL from your current database, Postgres will understand it and little to no extra effort is needed. SQL can be exported to recreate both the structure of your database and the content of its tables.

Answer (score -2):

MySQL is a highly scalable database used by some of the largest and most active sites on the interwebs.   I'd have some really good testing benchmarks showing Postgres is going to give you a significant advantage before switching over.

Comment: Check out this one: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/11/30/interesting-mysql-and-postgresql-benchmarks/